# How to shrink the size of a DB in MSSQL usign SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-administration

I'm facing an issue with a database on my production server, and I could use some guidance. Currently, the database is taking up a total of 2.6TB, including log files. To identify the tables that are using the most space, I ran a query I found [here](https://support.managed.com/kb/a227/how-to-find-large-tables-in-sql-database.aspx). Using that information, I managed to reduce the row count, and the table size decreased from 1.3TB to 151GB.

Now, here's where I need your help. I backed up the database to a .bak file with the intention of moving it to another disk. However, I noticed that the backup still requires the same 2.6TB of space. It seems like the size hasn't changed at all.

So, my question is, how can I further reduce the size of the database? I don't have a large number of views, just around 20, and the database contains approximately 900 tables. Are there any other factors I should consider to shrink the overall volume?

Manually scripting the process for each table isn't feasible since there are 900 tables in total. My current plan is to create a new database on the E: disk and transfer all the tables and views there.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Additionally, some context regarding the use of multiple disks:

The reason I'm looking to reduce the database size is that my client has allocated only 2TB for this server, and I need to decrease the size of two other databases as well. Currently, I'm using disk F:, a temporary 3TB HDD, because the initial 2TB is not even enough to restore the databases. Ultimately, my goal is to reduce the size of all the databases and move them back to the E: disk, which is a permanent 2TB HDD.

Thank you all in advance for your assistance!

Comment: additional info, the server is using SQL Server and SSMS 2017

Comment: What is the recovery model? What is the size of the transaction log file(s)?

Comment: `DBCC SHRINKDB` maybe? it's unclear if you shrunk large tables but didn't shrink the data files, or whether the data files grew again.

Comment: @nvogel i might need to get back to you on the recovery model, I am no longer in the office can't access it, I dont remember. The log is around 150GB.

Comment: @Charlieface I'll try in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: It's usually far cheaper to extend disk size then it is to employ someone to go through this manual archiving process, not to mention data loss involved.... but anyway looks like that's what you're stuck with

Comment: We tried something based on a suggestion from a senior colleague. We created a temporary database with corresponding tables and inserted 5 million rows into it. Then, we inserted those rows back into the original database after the original table had been dropped. Not sure if it's the right way, but we gave it a shot.

Honestly, none of us on the team are experienced in this area. We mainly focus on BI development, and the team handling this issue is tied up with recovering from a ransomware attack. But since we really need the server up and running, we decided to give it a try ourselves.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid welp not in my country :')

Comment: OK understood (my comment was not very helpful in this case). Anyway first try `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` as mentioned. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Will do, i'll update this post when I have tried it tomorrow. Thank you for the help! 

Comment: I just want to point out that shrinking your database will fragment any indexes you have in your database which will impact query performance until you re-index your tables

Comment: The best way ton "compact" a database is to : 1) REBUILD all indexes and heap tables. 2) use SHRINKFILE. But this will take a lot of time. The first part can be done only for the table that you have delete a great amount of rows...