# DBCC ShrinkDatabase is increasing my file size

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Yesterday, I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76405385/how-to-shrink-the-size-of-a-db-in-mssql-usign-ssms?noredirect=1#comment134740726_76405385) about how to reduce the size of a database. The community suggested using the command `dbcc shrinkdatabase`. I followed their advice and ran the command for over 24 hours. However, I encountered an error because my hard disk drive was full. Instead of decreasing the file size, the `dbcc shrinkdatabase` command seemed to be increasing it (*see photo links*). Moreover, the original free space in the database is now filled up, even though no additional data was added. Did I make a mistake?

This is the exact query I ran:
`DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (<DB>,1); GO` changed it to `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (<DB>,10); GO` after I ran out of space (currently still running, nad have not finished. Stopped in the middle)

Please note:

- I am aware that this will fragment my Indexes, and I am fine with that
- This is a Dev environment, no additional data goes in nor out
- I am running SQL Server and SSMS 2017

[Original Free Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaiQb.png)

[After running the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ1Oj.png)

Can someone please help me. Is there something I did wrong? Should I change the query?

Comment: This seems like a question for [dba.se] *not* [so].

Comment: As Thom pointed out - this is probably better posted on the other forum.  With that said - after purging data in the data file you can shrink that file (DBCC SHRINKFILE).  Once that has completed you can then shrink the log file.  Since this is in DEV - change the recovery model to simple before shrinking.